# json path in mariadb

Tags: mysql, mariadb

currently using mysql 5.7  I can execute the following query accessing a json field in the database:

```
select myData->'$[0].dataflow' from flowtable limit 1;
```

If I try the same query on  MariaDB it does not work, is there any solution to this problem? I thought MariaDB was fully compatible with mysql and what would it be the correspondent MariaDB syntax?

cheers

Answer (score 2):

In MySQL, [`JSON_EXTRACT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-extract) was added in 5.7.8:

> [JSON_EXTRACT(json_doc, path[, path] ...)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-extract)
>
> ...
>
> MySQL 5.7.9 and later supports the -> operator as shorthand for this (JSON_EXTRACT()) function ...
>
> ...

In MariaDB (starting with 10.2.3) use [`JSON_EXTRACT()`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/json_extract/) function, since `->` operator is not currently implemented.

MySQL:

```sql
SELECT `myData` -> '$[0].dataflow'
FROM `flowtable`
LIMIT 1;
```

MySQL and MariaDB:

```sql
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(`myData`, '$[0].dataflow')
FROM `flowtable`
LIMIT 1;
```

See, MySQL [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/65svsRKJcnngt7nKN1rJGa/0) and MariaDB [dbfiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=5994cd914a8131cd3e63e9757fa45b23).

Comment: Does mariadb 10.4 support `->`?

Comment: It is not yet implemented (2020-05-09) and it does not sound as if it would happen soon:

[MariaDB Server / MDEV-13594: Support for JSON operators column->path and column->>path](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-13594)